# Hover эффект у карточки

Tags: html, css, css-animation, hover

Правильно ли будет если я сделаю `img` как бэкграунд, а сами элементы, которые должны появляться при наведении, сделаю `opacity: 0` (при наведении `opacity` будет равняться 1).
[image: сами фото карточки]

Comment: то что вы описали - в целом подойдет

Comment: Правильно, а почему возникают сомнения?

Comment: Просто впервые с таким сталкиваясь т.к. новичек, и думал как правильней сделать

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class='bgImage' >
    <!-- bgImage задаёшь картинку как бэкграунд -->
    <div class="someBlocks">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores, saepe.
        </p>
    </div>
    <!-- в класс someBlocks кладёшь всё что нужно отбразить при наведении -->
</div>
```

И обязательно стили

```
.bgImage{
  background-image: url('image.jpg');
}
.someBlocks{
  display: none;
}
/*По умолчанию someBlocks скрыт*/
.bgImage:hover .someBlocks{
  display: block;
}
```

Но при наведении должен отобразиться